# How can specify negation of ion-tabs?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new in ionic, I try to use ion-tabs to navigate, but I am facing some problem with it, my application have two tags "Home" and "Option", "Home" have Sub tabs

```
             tag
       _______|_________
       |               |
      Home           option
       |
      sub
```

my problem is:
When I navigate from "Home" tag to Sub tag, then navigate to "Option tag" and try to return to  "Home" tag, I return to sub tag not to "Home" tag.

How can I return to "Home" tag not to Sub tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is per design, as every single tab has its own history stack. If you want to use single stack for all tabs, you can't use `ion-tabs` directive, you have to make it up on your own.

Example by [jason-engage](https://github.com/jason-engage) from [github issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2997#issuecomment-121084093) (change as appropriate):

```
<ion-view class="tabs-container">

    <!-- Single UI VIEW -->
    <ion-nav-view name="tabview"></ion-nav-view>

    <!-- TABS -->
    <div class="tabs tabs-icon-top">
        <a class="tab-item" ng-click="goTab1()" ng-class="{ active : settings.isTab1}">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-flame"></i> Tab1
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" ng-click="goTab2()" ng-class="{ active : settings.isTab2 }">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-location"></i> Tab2
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" ng-click="goTab3()" ng-class="{ active : settings.isTab3, 'has-badge' : settings.numberOfBadges != 0 }">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-chatboxes"></i> Tab3 <span class="badge badge-assertive" ng-if="settings.numberOfBages != 0">{{settings.numberOfBadges}}</span>
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" ng-click="goTab4()" ng-class="{ active : settingsTab4}">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-people"></i> Tab4
        </a>
    </div>

</ion-view>
```